# Why this selected area is bigger than the component area?

Tags: altium

I am new to Altium, this is my first board development. My question is why the selection area is bigger than the component area, How to remove it{because I can't able to place another component near to them}?
Note: I used Ultra Librarian to download Component Library.
Thank You[image]

Comment: This could be caused by a flaw in the library itself (for example, a primitive or object on a hidden layer). Where did you find this footprint?

Comment: I found it from Ultra Library. Yes, correct. I found some footprint primitive on the mechanical layer. Thanks for your kind information. Now I re-edited the same footprint. Problem solved...Thank You, Mr@DerStrom8

Comment: Glad to hear you got it solved!